# Different behavior of exception with async method

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library, async-await

Supposed you have 2 `async` method define as bellow:

```
public async Task<TResult> SomeMethod1()
{
    throw  new Exception();
}

public async Task<TResult> SomeMethod2()
{
    await Task.Delay(50);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Now if you `await` on those 2 methods the behavior will be pretty much the same. But if you are getting the task the behavior is different.

If I want to cache the result of such a computation but only when the task run to completion.
I have to take care of the 2 situation:

### First Situation:

```
public Task<TResult> CachingThis1(Func<Task<TResult>> doSomthing1)
{
    try
    {
       var futur = doSomthing1()
       futur.ContinueWith(
               t =>
               {
                  // ... Add To my cache
               },
               TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
    }
    catch  ()
    {
        // ... Remove from the pending cache
        throw;
    }
}
```

### Second Situation

```
public Task<TResult> CachingThis2(Func<Task<TResult>> doSomthing)
{
    var futur = SomeMethod2();
    futur.ContinueWith(
       t =>
       {
           // ... Add To my cache
       },
       TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
    futur.ContinueWith(
       t =>
       {
          // ... Remove from the pending cache
       },
       TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

Now I pass to my caching system the method that will execute the computation to cache.

```
cachingSystem.CachingThis1(SomeMethod1);
cachingSystem.CachingThis2(SomeMethod2);
```

Clearly I need to duplicate code in the "`ConinueWith` on faulted" and the catch block.
Do you know if there is a way to make the exception behave the same whether it is before or after an await?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, your catch block will never execute as the exception propagation for the async methods are different.

Comment: You must be true but my example miss something crucial that I have omit. See my edit

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference in the exception handling required for both `SomeMethod1` and `SomeMethod2`. They run exactly the same way and the exception would be stored in the returned task.

This can easily be seen in this example;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var task = SomeMethod1();
    }
    catch
    {
        // Unreachable code
    }
}

public static async Task SomeMethod1()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

No exception would be handled in this case since the returned task is not awaited.

There is however a distinction between a simple `Task`-returning method and an `async` method:

```
public static Task TaskReturning()
{
    throw new Exception();
    return Task.Delay(1000);
}

public static async Task Async()
{
    throw new Exception();
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

You can avoid code duplication by simply having an `async` wrapper method that both invokes the method and `await`s the returned task inside a single `try-catch` block:

```
public static async Task HandleAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await TaskReturning();
        // Add to cache.
    }
    catch
    {
        // handle exception from both the synchronous and asynchronous parts.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what I3arnon said in his answer, in case you `ContinueWith` on *async* method without the `TaskContinuationOptions` you specify, exception captured by the `Task` parameter you receive in the continuation handler can be handled in the following way:

```
SomeMethod1().ContinueWith(ProcessResult);
SomeMethod2().ContinueWith(ProcessResult);
```

With `ProcessResult` handler which looks like:

```
private void ProcessResult<TResult>(Task<TResult> task)
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        //remove from cahe
    }
    else if (task.IsCompleted)
    {
        //add to cache
    }
}
```